# export SOCKS_SERVER not working

Tags: networking, proxy, tor, socks5

I try `$ export socks_proxy=127.0.0.1:9150` and `$ wget http://icanhazip.com/` but still show previous IP (icanhazip.com show IP). Tor working correctly on Firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not make an application use socks proxy if it doesn't support it. Firefox supports socks proxy that's why you can simply change the proxy settings in Firefox to make it work.

However, for apps that don't support Socks proxy, you can use [Proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/) instead. It is very easy to setup and use. It comes pre-configured for use with Tor.

Debian family:

```
sudo apt-get install proxychains
```

Red hat family:

```
sudo yum install proxychains
```

Usage:

```
proxychains wget http://icanhazip.com/
```

Answer (score 2):

`man wget` suggests wget doesn't support socks proxies. In any case, the term 'socks' doesn't show up in the man or info docs.